# what happens when Calling Overridden method from with in it?

Tags: java, class, methods

i was writing **Rational** class in java to do basic math operation and  i want to override methods from
**Number class** and **Comparable interface**. i have done that for *doubleValue* & *compareTo* methods.

As we know that **BigInteger class** also *extends* **Number class**, so i am confused that which method is being called in *doubleValue* because i have already **override** *doubleValue* & *compareTo* and calling *doubleValue* with in *doubleValue* & *compareTo* with in *compareTo*. and it's seems silly too.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Rational extends Number implements Comparable<Rational>{

    // Data fields for numerator and denominator
    private BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE;

    // Construct a rational with default properties
    Rational(){
        numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
        denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    Rational(BigInteger numerator,BigInteger denominator){
        BigInteger gcde = numerator.gcd(denominator);
        BigInteger temp = BigInteger.valueOf( (long)(denominator.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)) );
        this.numerator =  temp.multiply(numerator.divide(gcde));
        this.denominator = (denominator.abs()).divide(gcde);
    }
    
    // subtract a rational number to this rational a/b - r.a/r.b = a*r.b - r.a*b/r.b*b
    public Rational subtract(Rational r){
        BigInteger n = (numerator.multiply(r.getDenominator())).subtract(denominator.multiply(r.getNumerator())); 
        BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(r.getDenominator());
        return new Rational(n,d);
    }
    // Return numerator
    public BigInteger getNumerator(){
        return numerator;
    }
    // Return denominator
    public BigInteger getDenominator(){
       return denominator;
    }
    @Override // Implement the abstract doubleValue method in Number
    public double doubleValue(){
        return numerator.doubleValue()/denominator.doubleValue();
    }
    @Override // Implement the abstract longValue method in Number
    public long longValue(){
        return (long)doubleValue();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rational r){
        return (this.subtract(r).getNumerator()).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }
}
```

Comment: `numerator` and `denominator` are declared as `BigInteger`s and defined as `BigInteger`s as well, so if you call methods on them you're calling `BigInteger`'s methods. It doesn't matter what your class extends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public double doubleValue(){
    return numerator.doubleValue()/denominator.doubleValue();
}
```

`numerator` is a `BigInteger` so `BigInteger.doubleValue()` is being called. Same with `denominator`. It does not matter that your class also happens to have a `doubleValue()` function. `numerator` and `denominator` are a different class than your `Rational` class.

```
          Number
          /   \
BigInteger     Rational
    |              |
doubleValue   doubleValue
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's helpful to get better understanding.